# Android file explorer to open any file in any app

Tags: gratis, android, file-management

What free file explorers for Android allow to open any file extension in any app?

(Ideally, there should also be a widget to go to a specific folder, or it should be able to always start in a specific folder.)

Answer (score 1):

The [X-plore File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore) is very versatile in opening files in different apps.